# How can I combine to columns that consist of lists?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

I want to combine the two columns position and . They look like this:
`position = c("123, 45", "67, 891, 23")` and `substitution = c("A/B, C/D", "E/F, G/H, J/K")` so that I get a column that looks like this:

`combined = c("A123B, C45D", "E67F, G891H, J23K")`

basically I want to replace the `/` in `substitution` with the number from `position` that has the same "index" (It's not an index yet, because it's just a long string).
Any ideas?

I want to create a column for amino acids substitutions from their position and their reference and mutated amino acid, which I unfortunately have in this weird format.

Here's a small example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(name = c("A", "B"),
             position = c("123, 45", "67, 891, 23"),
             substitution = c("A/B, C/D", "E/F, G/H, J/K"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the split-apply-combine approach twice.

1. Split `position` and `substitution` column on `","`. Make them as new columns (with `"_1"`) to preserve the original columns.
2. Split the splitted `substitution` column on "/" to get individual characters as vector.
3. Using `sprintf` create a string in required order.
4. Paste the string together as comma-separated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(position, substitution), 
          ~strsplit(.x, ", "), .names = "{col}_1"), 
         substitution_1 = map(substitution_1, ~strsplit(.x, "/")), 
         combined = map2_chr(position_1, substitution_1, \(x, y) {
           toString(map2_chr(x, y, \(p, q) sprintf("%s%s%s", q[1], p, q[2])))
          })) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_1"))

#  name  position    substitution  combined         
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>            
#1 A     123, 45     A/B, C/D      A123B, C45D      
#2 B     67, 891, 23 E/F, G/H, J/K E67F, G891H, J23K
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
df %>%
    separate_rows(-name, sep = ",\\s+") %>%
    summarise(
        combined = toString(map2_chr(substitution, position, \(x, y) sub("/", y, x))),
        .by = name
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  name  combined
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     A123B, C45D
2 B     E67F, G891H, J23K
```

Answer (score 0):

All nice answers. A friend of mine came up with a different solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(name = c("A", "B"),
             position = c("123, 45", "67, 891, 23"),
             substitution = c("A/B, C/D", "E/F, G/H, J/K"))

df <- 
  df |>
  separate_longer_delim(c(position, substitution), ", ") |>
  mutate(combined = paste0(substring(substitution, 1, 1), position, substring(substitution, 3, 3))) |>
  group_by(name) |>
  summarise(
    position = paste(position, collapse = ","),
    substitution = paste(substitution, collapse = ","),
    combined = paste(combined, collapse = ",")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good answers. Here´s another one, all-tidyverse but without superseded functions:

```
library(tidyverse)    

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(-name, delim = ", ") %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(substitution, names = c("start", "end"), delim = "/") %>% 
  mutate(name, combined = paste0(start, position, end), .keep = "none") %>% 
  summarise(.by = name, combined = str_flatten_comma(combined))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  name  combined         
  <chr> <chr>            
1 A     A123B, C45D      
2 B     E67F, G891H, J23K
```